# Ubuntu 22.04 How to share internet from Wifi over Ethernet?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I want to share my Wifi in my laptop which is running Ubuntu 22.04 to my Beaglebone Black(BBB) which is running Linux compiled with Buildroot. I have searched and read other answers in the internet but none of them works for me.
I have set a static address(10.42.0.2) for the BBB, and I can ping the Laptop's Wifi Adaptor(192.168.43.246) and the Laptop's Shared Ethernet Address(shared by creating a new connection and sharing to all, IP: 10.42.0.1) from the BBB. I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or anything else from the BBB, what should I do? Any pointers are appreciated.

How do I use the nm-connection-editor to achieve the above?

Comment: Interested in how this goes as I have a similar scenario with my Raspberry Pi. Lemme know, and Good luck.

Comment: Sure will do so. Last time I had successfully done so using Ubuntu 22.04. A day later the same steps did not work. Tried harder and lost internet in my Ubuntu(my inexperience using ip route add/del commands and default gateways). Then I tried using Windows 10 network bridge and succeeded. Then could not reproduce them again All firewalls down! What we want is a reliable and REPRODUCIBLE solution to the problem. Thank you for the best wishes...